# VS2012 How to turn off editor tab colouring?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, customization, productivity-power-tools

I strain to read the tabs in the source code editor of Visual Studio 2012. 
I don't even understand what the different colors mean? They seem totally random. Black on brown or black on blue.... who choose that?

[image]

So I would like to turn off the colouring for the tabs and revert to black on white, or a light grey.

I've looked in:

> Options>> Environment (General / Font and Colors)

but I cant see anything relevant. So how can I do this please?

Comment: The tab colours probably correspond with which project those source files are from.

Comment: @congusbongus Indeed they did/do. Now so obvious.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Looks like you might have [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) installed? If so turn off Custom Document Well or look in the *Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > Advanced*, there is an option to set colour to Visual Studio.

Comment: on current version: - *Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Document Tab Well -> General -> Tab UI ->* untick *"Color tabs by project"*

Comment: In my case : Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > General > Tab Appearance group - Color tabs by project (uncheck)

Comment: Note that this is actually a pain to set; if you click on other settings, it reverts and fights with you.

Answer (score 9):

Or you could set: (In VS2015)

Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > **Advanced**

Then under Colors and Gradients panel, in the **Selected Tab** drop down choose **VS Colors** ,

This allows you to keep colored tabs by project yet highlights the selected tab clearly, win win...

[image]

My selected Tab is now bright Blue all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The colors of each tab comes from **productivity power tools**. For each project power tools assign a colors, so developer can easily detect a file(if contain same name) belongs to which project.

For VS 2013 & 2015 you can easily remove those color by unchecked **Colors tab by project** following below steps

go to *Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well > General*

[image]