# VS 2017 dark theme changed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, themes, productivity-power-tools

I am using the Dark theme in Visual Studio 2017 and have productivity power tools installed. In the past week, some of the similar word highlight colors have switched to white on white. It used to be white on blue.

[image: password highlighted]

If I select the word "password" in the code, it is white on blue, but if I select the word in comments, I get white on white in code.

I have tried changing the color theme to Light and back to Dark. I have also set the Text Editor settings back to default.

Comment: Underneath Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors, if you have **Text Editor** selected. Do any of the options in the list of items show up as anything **not** Default? For example if you click **"Plain Text"** and then using the down arrow key to iterate through the list.. Do any of the foreground/background options show up as not default?

Comment: Everything says Default next to the color. I'm not sure which Display item to look for, so I just scrolled through them all.

Comment: Okay, that's what I wanted you to do just to make sure.. This one is new.. Just trying to track down what could possibly be the issue, sorry for the questions. What language are you using? Looks like `C#` correct? Does this occur for all files or just specific ones? Lastly, In the top of the text editor, you should see three drop downs. Does the left most drop down say your project name or does it say "Miscellaneous File"?

Comment: Okay, after doing a little research online, it looks like Productivity Power Tools has their own set of color overrides in their settings. According to some other (slightly unrelated) StackOverflow pages I've found, it looks like their menu is under **Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools** and apparently there are some other sections underneath there. I don't have it installed at the moment so I can't verify all the options if gives you, but maybe there's a checkbox to turn the coloring back to default (or PPT specific coloring off)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081099/vs2012-how-to-turn-off-editor-tab-colouring

Comment: @Chris: You are correct. There is an option in Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > General > "Show matches in the editor" that was including comments when highlighting. While handy, the broken color it was giving me was distracting, so I disabled it. If you want to post your comment, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > General > "Show matches in the editor" that was including comments when highlighting. While handy, the broken color it was giving me was distracting, so I disabled it.